# vim-ruby installed but mapping not showing up

Tags: ruby, vim

I have installed vim-ruby using Pathogen, and even though the auto indentation seems to work fine, some of the mappings that are shown in the Wiki, are not showing up.

Specifically this one:

```
imap <S-CR>    <CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc
```

Here is my vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start

call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set encoding=utf-8
set termencoding=utf-8

set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set autowriteall

set autoindent
set smarttab
set expandtab

syntax on             
filetype on           
filetype indent on    
filetype plugin on    
autocmd Filetype html setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype eruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype css setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype scss setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype php setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4
autocmd Filetype coffee setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype json setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd Filetype liquid setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2

set smartindent               
set autoindent
set nocindent
set wrap

set magic
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch
set hlsearch

set lazyredraw
set ruler
set laststatus=2
set cmdheight=1
set number
set numberwidth=1
set cursorline

if has('gui_running')
        set background=light
else
        set background=dark
end
let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
colorscheme solarized

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline_theme = 'solarized'
set timeoutlen=50
set noshowmode

let mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>ne :NERDTree<cr>
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right" " Make nerdtree open on right

if has('gui_macvim')
  set lines=999 columns=9999
endif

set gfn=Monaco:h12

noremap <silent> <Space> :silent noh<Bar>echo<CR>
nnoremap - :Switch<CR>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Terminal vim or gvim?

Comment: I am using MVIM, but it happens the same with vim in a iterm2 terminal.

Comment: Which plugin are you using (and what page on the wiki are you looking at). I don't see the mapping in this plugin https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby. (Edit: I have a feeling the wiki on the github project is out of date.)

Comment: I am using https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock and looking at this page https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/wiki/VimRubySupport

Comment: What does that plugin (vim-textobj-rubyblock) have anything to do with vim-ruby?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby